# Why my code doesn't work?

Tags: python, wxpython

Why doesn't this work?

```
for i in [a, b, c]:
    i.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(VarFiles[str(i)]))
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in ?
  File "codecc.py", line 724, in ?
    app = MyApp(0)   # stdio to console; nothing = stdio to its own window
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WorldViz\Vizard30\bin\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 7978, in __init__
    self._BootstrapApp()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\WorldViz\Vizard30\bin\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 7552, in _BootstrapApp
    return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "codecc.py", line 719, in OnInit
    frame = VFrame(parent=None)
  File "codecc.py", line 374, in __init__
    i.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(VarFiles[str(i)]))
KeyError: "<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x165aeab0> >"
```

Interestingly, this works:

```
 i.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(VarFiles["i"]))
```

but this doesn't:

```
 i.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(VarFiles[i]))
```

The last one returns an wxpython object with the same name as `i`, thus breaking the loop. So I need to find a way of returning the name of this object. But `i.__name__` doesn't work.

Comment: *python is not allowing me to do it* and what is "allowing" you to do? Do you get any errors?

Comment: If functionA, (a short list of functions), functionD are meant to be function calls, that's your problem. These are not syntactically correct.

Comment: Try this: `for i in [nameA, nameB, nameC, ...(a very long list continues goes here), nameZZZZ]: pass` and try this: `nameA.functionA.functionB.functionC.functionD(nameA)`. Which one works?

Comment: And can't you use: `i.functionA(i.functionB(i.functionC(i.functionD(i))))`

Comment: nameA.functionA.functionB.functionC.functionD(nameA) obviously works, but that means not using a loop. I would like to use a loop or I am going to have too many lines in my code for doing this.

Comment: why do you have three identical lines of code in your for loop?

Comment: Didn't know you can use brackets in python =O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I """"fixed"""" my code:

```
    list_a = [a, b, c]
    list_b = ["a", "b", "c"]
    [i.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(VarFiles[list_b[list_a.index(i)]])) for i in list_a]
```

Comment: Thank you SilentGhost, this zip function helps me with this and some other things I have been trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

As the traceback says you have a `KeyError`. Since `i` is an object when you do `str(i)` you get `"<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x165aeab0> >"`, such key doesn't exist in a `VarFiles` container.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the for loop or the way you write your list.

Comment: So, what should I use instead of str(i) to get a, b and c instead of "<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x165aeab0> >" ?

Comment: @relima: well, what's inside `VarFiles`? how are those things related to the `i` instances?

Comment: VarFiles is a dictionary which returns the path for an image when a, b and or c are given to it.

VarFiles[a] returns: ./path/to/img/image.png

it works well everywhere but in this loop.

Comment: @relima: so why don't you give `i` to it? why do you give `str(i)` to it?

Comment: it gives the same error... for some reason, "a" works but str(a) returns this other object that has been instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Break it down using a single case. Where is the error in this?

```
s = str(a)
v = VarFiles[s]
w = wx.Bitmap(v)
a.SetBitmap(w)
```

Comment: If I do: s = "a"   ,  it works. If I do:  s = str(a)  , it doesn't and I get: KeyError: "<wx._core.MenuItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxMenuItem *' at 0x165924b0> >"

Comment: I see above that @SilentGhost has elicited that `VarFiles` is a dictionary. So what should the key to `VarFiles` be in this instance? Show us what any of a, b, or c is and then show us the construction of the VarFiles dictionary.

Comment: a = wx.MenuItem(M[1], wx.ID_EXIT, _("E&xit \tAlt+F4"), _(" Exits"))
------
VarFiles["a"] = os.path.join(Current_DIR, 'textures/image.png')